# Baseline predictors model

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

I implemented baseline predictors model (like it is told in Recommender systems handbook pp 148-149).

```
b_ui = mu + b_i + b_u
```

where mu is overall average rating and `b_i, b_u` are parameters. I calculate them with decoupling method, that uses parameters `lambda_2, lambda_3`. I firstly set parameters static 25 and 10 respectively, but it gives not enough accuracy. Can you tell how can I improve parameters using learning data?